# Conectarse a maquina virtual con SSH generado por Vagrant, vía WinSCP

Tags: ssh, vagrant

he montado una maquina virtual con S.O Ubuntu 16.04 mediante Vagrant, siguiendo las instrucciones indicadas en el proyecto Freeciv, teniendo como host un Windows 10.

La máquina está montada correctamente, y quisiera poder acceder vía WinSCP.

Tengo un BAT preparado que me permite invocar WinSCP,

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe"
>   scp://vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222 /log="./winscp.log" /loglevel=2
>   /privatekey="xxxxxxxxxx\.vagrant\machines\default\virtualbox\private_key"

pero el log me indica que no puedo usar dicha private_key

Si trato de acceder mediante vagrant, usando

> vagrant up

obtengo un error similar.

Este es el error que me viene a dar usando tanto Vagrant como WinSCP

> Authentication log (see session log for details): Unable to use key
>   file "xxxxxxxx\private_key" (OpenSSH SSH-2 private key) Using username
>   "vagrant". Authentication failed.

He probado diferentes combinaciones, sin éxito

Comment: Hola bienvenido a [es.so], vi que tu pregunta estaba en español pero la tradujiste al inglés. Puedes revertir tu edición, o la pregunta puede ser cerrada

Comment: Hola Quique Olaso, estás en el sitio de Stack Overflow en español, por favor traduce la pregunta. Lee [ask] para más información y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

encontré el siguiente enlace [this](https://superuser.com/questions/912304/how-do-you-convert-an-ssh-private-key-to-a-ppk-on-the-windows-command-line) y una de las respuestas funcionó para mí:

> 1) obtener el PuTTY Key Generator(PuTTYgen)
>
> 2) abrir PuTTYgen
>
> 3) ir a "Conversions"
>
> 4) ir a "Import key"
>
> 5) localizar el archivo key original
>
> 6) abrir
>
> 7) guardar nueva clave como a PPK file, cliqueando en "Save private key"

Parece ser que debía convertir la clave privada generada por Vagrant (en realidad, openSSH) a una clave privada de extensión PPK. Eso hice, generando el nuevo fichero en la misma ruta que el original.

Tras ello, cambié el contenido de mi BAT script tal que así:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe"
>   scp://vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222 /log="./winscp.log" /loglevel=2
>   /privatekey="xxxxxxxx\.vagrant\machines\default\virtualbox\private_key.ppk"

Comment: Hola Quique Olaso, estás en el sitio de Stack Overflow en español, por favor traduce la respuesta. Lee [answer] para más información.